# Automatically Updating Stale Data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a social networking structure in my Firebase Database that provides a user following system

```
user-followers
  -F2iRZkwfuTcKUvd7uYD0jwWeJ7T2
    -KgkkWy5xesvcFcL9GMh: 
      -username: 'billybob'
      -fullName: 'Billy Robertson'
    -KgkoZpD0GP687J_5Zh5: true
      -username: 'coolguy55'
      -fullName: 'Jim Davis'
```

This works fine for reading a summarized view of a given user's followers. However, when a user updates their profile, say their username or fullName, the data under `user-followers` immediately becomes outdated.

Is there any feasible solution to keeping this nested data updated, without writing an extra function when a user's profile is updated? To me this seems unavoidable

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: which one did you use to solve this? .onWrite()? .onCreate()? .onUpdate()? .onDelete()? Any change you can provide any sample code on how you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that runs in response to writes that happen in one place in your database so that other changes can be made to keep things consistent where data needs to be duplicated.

Comment: I had no idea this was available. Thanks very much!

Comment: It was released in beta just a month ago! https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/introducing-cloud-functions-for-firebase.html

Comment: thanks @Doug !I have question. My app is in iOS and I am using Firebase DB without any intermediate server. So can I directly add trigger from iOS app..?

Comment: Any Firebase client can trigger a function that runs on Cloud Functions.